How to make a transaction PRIOR to another in postgresql?
I have 2 tables with the relationship of one-to-many.



Table A
Table B




id
id


is_running
a_id



is_running



And I'm doing such things:



Transaction 1
Transaction 2
Transaction 3




UPDATE table_a SET is_running = false WHERE id=1
INSERT INTO table_b values (3, 1, true)
UPDATE table_b SET is_running = false WHERE id=2


SELECT id FROM table_b WHERE a_id=1 AND is_running=true
SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE id=1 AND is_running=true





Transaction 1 updates A and get all related B which is running.

Transaction 2 inserts a row into table_b ONLY IF related A is running.

Transaction 3 updates a row in table_b.


I hope a priority strategy like 3 > 1 > 2. In other words:

Transaction 2 would just roll back if it detects transaction 1 is commited.

Transaction 1 would wait transaction 3 to commit so that the rows it selected is up to date.


I tried to make the SELECT in transaction 2 as FOR UPDATE to ensure the serialization, but it doesn't meet my demand since transaction 2 should be forced to roll back when transaction 1 is commited.

Use advisory locks if these 3 transactions are issued by different workers. If they all need to be handled by a single worker, you can use dblink() to emulate autonomous transaction behaviour, letting you run whole other, parallel transactions and let it commit/rollback, all from within another transaction that doesn't have to commit/rollback itself.

It would be helpful if you added some context, what you're trying to achieve, what problem this logic is meant to solve or what anomaly/unwanted behaviour it's trying to avoid. In general it's best to run fewer statements in fewer transactions, reduce locking and external state dependencies. There might be a simpler and more convenient way to solve the problem, but first you need to explain what the problem is.

You could also merge the multiple statements in each of these flows into a single statement using subqueries, WITH CTE's and RETURNING clauses. Once merged, they leave no window of time between them, removing the opportunity for any concurrent worker to squeeze in an interfering commit. Combined with explicit for update locks, it could potentially simplify the whole problem away.

Strictly serializing the three transactions is trivial if you run them on the same database connection, one after the other... but that is obviously not what is happening, and the three transactions have to run in different sessions.
If you want to serialize them, you need to coordinate the sessions that run the statements. You could do that in different ways:

Take explicit ACCESS EXCLUSIVE locks on all tables affected by a transaction right at the beginning.
That is the fool's way. It would prevent all concurrent access, and if you do it frequently, you will run afoul of autovacuum, which can never finish processing your tables.

Take transaction-level advisory locks to explicitly coordinate the transactions.
That is a decent way to do it, but you have to explicitly code it.

Coordinate the sessions on the application side.
That can also work well, but is outside the scope of the database.

Use the SERIALIZABLE isolation level.
This is the best way to do it. The problems you are trying to avoid are transaction anomalies, that is, effects that could never happen in a serial execution. With SERIALIZABLE isolation, you are guaranteed to have no anomalies.
The price you are paying is that one of the transactions will get a serialization error, and it is up to the application to retry the transaction in such a case.


Note that none of my solutions provides the strict order of the three transactions that you desire. They just prevent then from running concurrently in a way that produces undesirable results. That is usually what is required for consistency.
If the three transactions really have to occur in a certain, deterministic order, then you should probably really run them in a single database session.
